# Why does my method get stuck when running in Azure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I have a method that executes the following code:

```
var subresulta1 = (from s in surveys
            select new SurveyViewModel()
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                Name = s.Name.Translation(Language.En),
                IsActive = s.IsActive,
                Locations = (from l in resulta.Select(a => a.Question.Location).Distinct()
                    select new LocationViewModel()
                    {
                        Id = l.Id,
                        Name = l.Name.Translation(Language.En),
                        Questions = (from q in resulta.Select(a => a.Question).Distinct()
                            where q.LocationId == l.Id
                            select new QuestionViewModel()
                            {
                                Text = q.QuestionText.Translation(Language.En),
                                Scores = (from a in resulta
                                    where a.QuestionId == q.Id
                                    select new ScoreViewModel()
                                    {
                                        Value = (int) a.Value,
                                        PositionId = a.SurveyAnswers.PositionId,
                                        Date = a.SurveyAnswers.CreatedDate,
                                        Location = new LatLonViewModel()
                                        {
                                            Latitude = a.SurveyAnswers.Latitude,
                                            Longitude = a.SurveyAnswers.Longitude
                                        }
                                    }).ToList()
                            }).ToList()
                    }).ToList()

            }).ToList();
```

When I run it on my test machine (Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2012) it takes around 3s to complete. When I run it as app service connected to Azure SQL DB it completes after ~4 minutes. Application server pricing tier is "Standard: 1 Large" and DB server "S2", so I guess the performance of the machines is not an issue here. Of course the data in both databases is the same. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

**EDIT**
I do not think it is the SQL server issue. I think it is the app problem. I rewrote the code to obtain all data from DB first and then apply all the logic. This finishes faster (30s), but is still not comparable to the performance of my own server. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to look for wait stats when the query is running

Comment: sys.dm_exec_requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was 2-fold, but the biggest issue was the geo-location of the app and db instances in Azure. Next time you create a Web app in Azure, make sure that Web app and DB server are in the same region (e.g. West Europe). Be careful, because Azure will try to put random stuff by default (in my case it was Central/West US/Brazil).